# Reading selected files using starting name of file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have more than 1000 files in the same folder. I want to read selected files from it.

[image: File names]

Here randon_text is different in each file.
I have successfully fetched all file names in one list name **file_name_list**.

I want something like below

**file_name == part_0000 then Work1**

**file_name != _confirm or _start then work2**

I have done some part of the required work using the below code.
`for i in file_name_list:`
`if i.name == "part_0000"`

Here I don't know how to read file with matching text or the same format in python. 
I need something the same as **like** function in SQL so I can read files with initial text only.

Comment: You probably want to use a regex or `startswith()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in file_name_list: 
    if "part_0000" in i.name:
           if "part_00001" in i.name or "part_00002" in i.name:
               continue
           #enter your condition here....
```

Comment: How to write not condition with your comment  like if iI want to read all file except part_00001 and part_00002.

Comment: edited the code, using the `conitinue` it will skip the condition